# Bridge Networking on CentOS brctl error

Tags: networking, linux-networking, centos7, bridge

I am trying to bridge an interface to another one but when I execute `ifup br_wan` to the interface I get the error message below. It's on CentOS 7 and I have the exact same setup on another box so I'm unsure what's going wrong.

> Incorrect number of arguments for command Usage: brctl addbr  
>   add bridge

ifcfg-enp0s20f0

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
NAME=enp0s20f0
DEVICE=enp0s20f0
ONBOOT=yes
stp=yes
BRIDGE=br_wan
NM_CONTROLLED=no
NETWORKING_IPV6=no # disable ipv6
```

ifcfg-br_wan

```
DEVICEE=br_wan
TYPE=Bridge
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DELAY=0
NETWORKING_IPV6=no # disable ipv6
```

brctl show

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br_pran         8000.0008a20d13d8       no              enp0s20f1
br_wan          8000.0008a20d13d7       no              enp0s20f0
```

I dont really know why ifup is calling brctl so if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Did you copy and paste these text files? There is an obvious typo in your file `ifcfg-br_wan` as posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael said in the comments section you have a typo in your `ifcfg-br_wan` file.

Please edit the file and change the first line from `DEVICEE=br0` to `DEVICE=br0` and try again.